# Python, numpy, piecewise answer gets rounded

Tags: python, numpy, piecewise

I have a question with regards to the outputs of numpy.piecewise.

my code:

```
e=110
f=np.piecewise(e,[e<120,e>=120],[1/4,1])
print(f)
```

As a result i get:
0
and not the desired 0.25

Can someone explain me why piecewise seems to be rounding my answer?
Is there a way to go around this without doing?

```
e=110
f=np.piecewise(e,[e<120,e>=120],[1,4])/4
print(f)
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Python 2 or 3? `1/4 == 0` on Python 2, because it's floor division.

Comment: I don't think it's a numpy problem. Try `[1.0/4.0]` instead of `[1/4]` and check if this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`np.piecewise` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html):

> The output is the same shape and type as x

Integer in, integer out. If you want a floating-point output, you need to pass a float in:

```
e = 110.0
```

Additionally, if you're on Python 2, `1/4` will already just be `0` because that's floor division on Python 2, so you'll need to write something like `1.0/4.0` or just `0.25`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code 1/4 produces the int value which is 0. use `float(1)/4` which will produce its float value.

```
e=110
f=np.piecewise(e,[e<120,e>=120],[float(1)/4,1])
print(f)
```